# Foxfire Prototype error in parse-1.6.14.min.js

Tags: javascript, firefox, gwt, parse-platform, libgdx

While experimenting with my libGDX game using their GWT backend, hosted on Parse.com, and evaluating performance on various browsers, I encountered this warning from the Foxfire browser...

> mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create
>
> The offending code is at parse-1.6.14.min.js:16:10124

In researching this message, it seems like the warning is pertinent in that resulting code will indeed be slower if this construct is used; however, it is embedded in the parse js.min so I can't directly change anything. I didn't find anything Parse related to this warning message on stackoverflow or anywhere else.

Is this by design? or by mistake? Should I worry about it at all?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know parse but are you sure you cannot prevent this warning by changing your code? Are you re defining types after you created instances? Or re defining types using instances?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm rather certain it is in the parse .min.js file, only because when I remove the few references to parse, the message goes away. I don't use parse functionality for much at this point - simple boilerplate stuff right out of their manual...

Comment: This question is now moot in light of parse's recent announcement...